# How to make rails resource ids non-unique for every user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a rails app for users to manage tasks.
So when the user 1 creates a task, it will have the following URL:

```
user/task/1
```

Now another user (#2) creates a new task and it will look like:

```
user/task/2
```

If the first user will create add another one it will have the number 3. And so on. The new task will not reflect the amount of tasks a user has, but the amount of resources that is stored in my database.

I would like to have every user create tasks without seeing how many tasks are in the system in total. So everybody could have task 1,2,3.. as well as tasklist 1,2,3..

I guess one way to go is to have a new custom kind of ID and try to put it into the URL. Am I close? Maybe there's a good guide/a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the ordinal number for the task? For example `task/1` will always be the first task in the list even if that changes. Or do you want to assign custom ID's but have them be scoped to the user?

Comment: scoped to the user, yes

Comment: well in any case if is scoped to the user the url will be users/100/tasks/1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to accomplish, I would do this:

In your task model, I would add:

1. Add a `belongs_to` for the `user`
2. Add a integer column called `user_specific_identifier`

Then in the controller make sure to scope the queries to use the user:

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.where(user: current_user)
               .where(user_specific_identifier: params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

You might be able to use [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) to get your helpers to work properly by overriding what rails uses as the ID for that model. However I have not done this in cases where the ID is not unique.

You might want to checkout RailsCast [#314 Pretty URLs with FriendlyId](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast).

Comment: I thought about this but I don't think it will work: friendly_id expects "friendly ids" to be unique, and in this case ids are not unique, he will need to write a specific route for this I suppose.

Comment: You should not need a specific route, just make sure the queries are properly scoped in the controller (what the first `where` does).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to keep an ordinal on the user record which is incremented when you need a new task ID. Then, you will store this ID on the task, and override `#to_param` on your `Task` model, so that Rails' URL helpers will use it for URL generation.

So, you'll need a migration:

```
add_column :users, :task_count, :integer
add_index  :users, :task_count, unique: true

add_column :tasks, :user_task_id, :integer
add_index  :tasks, :user_task_id, unique: true
```

Then add a `before_create` filter on your Task model:

```
# Task
before_create :set_user_specific_id
def set_user_specific_id
  self.user_task_id = self.user.get_next_task_id!
end

def to_param
  self.user_task_id
end

# User
def get_next_task_id!
  # Atomic increment is used here to prevent race conditions from generating dupe IDs
  increment_counter :task_count
  reload
  self.task_count
end
```

Now you can use your URL helpers like `user_task_path(user, task)` to generate URLs that use the user-specific ID, rather than the actual row ID. Your finder would then be something like `Task.where(user_id: params[:user_id], user_task_id: params[:id])`.